# Spring Best Practice to Partition Application Properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My application properties file has gotten rather large, and I would like to know what is the best way to break it down?

All my configuration classes have these annotations:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("some.prefix")
```

And I have separate files for different profiles:

```
application.yml
application-dev.yml
application-qa.yml
```

How do I break it down, probably to something like this:

```
application.yml       additionalprop.yml
application-dev.yml   additionalprop-dev.yml
application-qa.yml    additionalprop-qa.yml
```

Comment: rather than doing this you can have all profiles in one application.yml file and select which every you want by vm arguments and what do you want to store in additionalprops file?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is the best solution but better then gather all yaml in one project.

What we do We split application profile by repository prod/dev/qa and in each repository We divide our properties as application.yaml and application-default.yaml 
In default are collected all standard properties like data source, security, cors, hystrix and other infra information. 
On the other hands in application.yaml we see specific for microservice configuration like mgmt, jpa, profiles, ports etc.

What it is the most important are the context and environments where you work and contract with your team what is the most proper for you.